# unwanted empty spaces apear at the end of page

Tags: html, css

```css
.article-image1 {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/gentleman-e1508436248648.png);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image1:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.article-image1>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image1:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*puzzle*/

.article-image2 {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/puzzle.png);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image2:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  top: -286px;
  right: 306px;
}

.article-image2>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image2:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*Maket*/

.article-image3 {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image3:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/minivan.png);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image3:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  top: -572px;
  right: 662px;
}

.article-image3>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image3:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*figure*/

.article-image4 {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image4:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/batman.png);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image4:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  top: -512px;
  right: 0px;
}

.article-image4>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image4:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*toys*/

.article-image5 {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image5:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/robot.png);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image5:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  top: -798px;
  right: 306px;
}

.article-image5>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image5:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*entertaimnt*/

.article-image6 {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image6:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/magician.png);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image6:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  top: -1084px;
  right: 662px;
}

.article-image6>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image6:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=lego">
<div class="ar-image1">
<div class="article-image1">
<p>لگو</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=puzzle">
<div class="ar-image2">
<div class="article-image2">
<p>پازل</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=maket">
<div class="ar-image3">
<div class="article-image3">
<p>ماکت</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=figure">
<div class="ar-image4">
<div class="article-image4">
<p>فیگور</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=toys">
<div class="ar-image5">
<div class="article-image5">
<p>اسباب بازی</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=entertaiment">
<div class="ar-image6">
<div class="article-image6">
<p>سرگرمی</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

I want to create a menu for my site with some clickable icons but some unwanted empty spaces appear when I use the code above. Also when I access the page with phone the icons appear completely of grid. you can check [my site](http://limootoys.com) to see what actually happens.  any help to eliminate these empty spaces would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly looking at your code, it looks like your implementing bootstrap, to have everything scale nicely on different view ports I would try implementing a solution as follows:

Under your entry-content div:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image1">
        <a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=lego">
            <div class="article-image1">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image2">
        <a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=puzzle">
            <div class="article-image2">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image3">
        <a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=maket">
            <div class="article-image3">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image4">
        <a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=figure">
            <div class="article-image4">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image5">
        <a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=toys">
            <div class="article-image5">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image6">
        <a style="display:block" href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=entertainment">
            <div class="article-image6">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For your css modify as follows:

```
.article-image1 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/gentleman-e1508436248648.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image1:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.article-image1>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image1:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*puzzle*/

.article-image2 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/puzzle.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image2:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.article-image2>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image2:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*Maket*/

.article-image3 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image3:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/minivan.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image3:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;;
}

.article-image3>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image3:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*figure*/

.article-image4 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image4:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/batman.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image4:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.article-image4>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image4:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;;
}


/*toys*/

.article-image5 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image5:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/robot.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image5:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.article-image5>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image5:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;;
}


/*entertaimnt*/

.article-image6 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
}

.article-image6:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/magician.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image6:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.ar-image6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.article-image6>p {
  display: none;
}

.article-image6:hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  color: #fed700;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.entry-content .img-icon {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This should give you your desired solution, currently with the fixes you have, your mobile doesn't scale properly. Let me know if this works or you have any questions!

Good luck,

James

---

EDITED FOR SIMPLICITY OF CODE:

---

To further reduce the clutter in your css, i.e. continually defining the same attributes for parent elements and avoiding using inline css in your html, look at the below modifications and see how I've implemented the class and ID of your article images, should be much easier for you to maintain if you intend on updating or changing anything!

HTML as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image">
        <a href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=lego">
            <div class="article-image" id="lego">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image">
        <a href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=puzzle">
            <div class="article-image" id="puzzle">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image">
        <a href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=maket">
            <div class="article-image" id="maket">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image">
        <a href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=figure">
            <div class="article-image" id="figure">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image">
        <a href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=toys">
            <div class="article-image" id="toys">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-icon">
    <div class="ar-image">
        <a href="http://limootoys.com/?product_cat=entertainment">
            <div class="article-image" id="entertainment">
                <p>لگو</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS as follows:

```
.ar-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.article-image {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
}

.article-image:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
    filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image:hover:before {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
    filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-image>p {
    display: none;
}

.article-image:hover>p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    color: #fed700;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 9999999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

#lego:before {
    background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/gentleman-e1508436248648.png);
}

#puzzle:before {
    background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/puzzle.png);
}

#maket:before {
    background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/minivan.png);
}

#figure:before {
    background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/batman.png);
}

#toys:before {
    background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/robot.png);
}

#entertainment:before {
    background-image: url(http://limootoys.com/wp-content/uploads/magician.png);
}

.entry-content .img-icon {
    padding: 10px;
}

.entry-content .img-icon a {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, you were right it didn't scale properly on mobile but with your code it is fixed!

Comment: No problem at all Ali, always happy to help. Check out the edited version I just updated below the original. Observe how I used the class and ID for the article-image to reduce redundancy in declaring attributes that are the same across all of your image icons. Also, try avoid using inline css at all costs, it will help you in the future when you're making  styling changes, that way you won't have to use !important or go back to your html to get the desired changes. Happy coding my friend!

Comment: What a beautiful piece of code! Thank you. I'm a noob at coding so your explanation helped a lot! I will keep them in mind.

Comment: Pleasure my friend! Your site is looking great, keep it up! And please up vote my answer if it was ideal :)!

Answer (score 1):

just remove the top,right atributes from all of this objects :
ar-image1,ar-image2,ar-image3,ar-image4,ar-image5,ar-image6

and add this to your css :

```
.entry-content a {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahele, I did as you suggested but now the icons in the first row don't have the same height! I want the Icons to be in two rows and three columns if possible.

Comment: try this :    .entry-content a {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
} .entry-content p {
    display: none;
}#content {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

Comment: You're a life saver! works like a charm. thank you so much.